# AI Seek behavior issue

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, game-engine, game-physics

```
@Override
public void update() {
    float c = TIME_DELTA * 10;
    Vector desiredVelocity = Vector.subtract(target, pos()).normalize().multiply(c);
    Vector steering = Vector.subtract(desiredVelocity, velocity);
    steering.truncate(0.4f);
    steering.multiply(0.0956023f); //divide by mass
    velocity.add(steering);
    velocity.truncate(3f);
    setX(getX() + velocity.x);
    setY(getY() + velocity.y);
}
```

I tried following this guide http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-steering-behaviors-seek--gamedev-849 and I have a problem with the implementation. When I run the code the sprite acts oddly and the x and y eventually turn into NaNs. I've tried looking it up and I've been messing with the code for days trying to get it to work, but I've had no success. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would start by logging the various states and decisions, then analyze the logs to see where it starts getting off-track.

Comment: I'd place a small bet on "normalize", because this may show odd behavior (including `NaN`s) when the vector length approaches zero. But as paphlet already said: Some simple outputs like `System.out.println("Changing position with velocity "+velocity)` etc. could already bring some insights.